# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2 - b^2}} = \frac{1/a}{\sqrt {1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Recently I have been reading physics book and saw interesting equation, like this:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2 - b^2}} = \frac{1/a}{\sqrt {1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}}}$$

But I still don't understand how to get the right part of the equation from left part, and I ask for the explaining of this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's wrong if $a<0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut makes a good point. Is there some assumption that $a>0$?

Answer (score 3):

Divide numerator and denominator by $a$ (where $a>0$). The denominator becomes
$$\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}}\times\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}.$$

Comment: Wow, it was easier than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For nonnegative $u$ and $v$, you can write $\sqrt{uv}=\sqrt{u}\cdot\sqrt{v}$. You also have, for any $u$, $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$. Use this here:

Assume $a^2\ge b^2$ and $a\ne0$, then

$$\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=\sqrt{a^2\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)}=\sqrt{a^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}=|a|\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$

If you take the inverse of the preceding, assuming further that $a\ne b$, then

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\dfrac{1}{|a|\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}}$$

Assume further that $a>0$, and

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\dfrac{1}{a\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}}$$

When you take a factor $a^2$ out of a square root, **never** forget the absolute value unless you are absolutely certain $a\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "how do we get from the left side of the equation to the right side of the equation. In that case, it's simple division by $a$ in both the numerator and denominator.

This is pretty easy to see in the numerator, but in the denominator, the $a$ is 'absorbed' into the square root as $a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove this in a reverse way

Lets start with $$\frac{1/a}{\sqrt {1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}}}$$
$$=\frac{1/a}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}}}$$
$$=\frac{1/a}{\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{a}(a)}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2 - b^2}}$$
Hence,$$\frac{1/a}{\sqrt {1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2 - b^2}}$$
which is nothing but,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2 - b^2}} = \frac{1/a}{\sqrt {1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}}}$$